# css media - screen width inconsistencies

Tags: jquery, html, css

css

```
 html{
    overflow-y:scroll;
    }
```

js

```
function showW(){
    var a=($(window).width());
    $('#show').html(a);
}
```

Result in Chrome is `1009`. Result in Firefox is `1007`. Why? What is the truth?

I tried to replace `width()` with `outerWidth()` - results are same.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:960px){...
```

This executes on `945px (Chrome)` and `943px - Firefox`.

Maybe, scrolbar is `15px` (945+15=960)

My Display Settings (win xp) is - `1024x768`.

Could someone explain this inconsistencies.

My final goal is to execute css media really on `960 px` (including scrollbar) in all browsers, or at least in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Inconsistent due to scrollbar, if you want to run something at max width 960 then use media queries. If you need to sync the js and media query width (they are different) then you can set a css rule in css and check for that in js

Comment: ^^ This.  The width is different because of the difference in the way the browser are rendered - nothing to do with your page contents, but the actual browser applications themselves.

Comment: @Huangism, Did you say this: screen width is different for windows, jquery and css? And, if css way is a valid one, 960 is including or excluding scrolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inconsistency is due to the scrollbar.

Look at this example using media query

http://jsfiddle.net/CU4Q6/

```
div {
    background: green;
    width: 300px
}

@media only screen and (max-width:300px){
    div {
        background: red;
    }
}
```

You can see the box changing colour after the scrollbar covers the box. So media query outputs the window width with scrollbar when it is present. On iPad, media query's width is the screen size (including the scrollbar when present). This makes sense because you don't want the width to change when the scrollbar appears because if that happens then it is possible to have media queries that alter the site at 2 very close width

If you need to sync the width from media query to js. Then you can add a css rule for an invisible element or a visible element (whatever) then use js to check for that css property when resizing the window.

It is important to note that people now uses all kinds of different devices to view webpages, it's not too important to target an exact width.